# Average Vlookup values if it Cell X matches Cell Y in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So here's my problem:

- I've got 2 sheets. (A and B).
- 2 Cells 2 Match (SheetA!A and SheetB!A)
- 6 Columns to average (B-C-D-E-F-G)

SheetA!A1 and SheetB!A1 If those two match, the average needs to be for cells B1-C1-D1-E1-F1-G1).

I've got a few thousands rows in each sheet. SheetA is the "Data Sheet" where all the data is. And SheetB is like my workbook, where all the stats will be.

I tried this function:

```
=AverageIf(SheetA!$A:$A;A2;SheetA!B:G)
```

I also tried

```
=average(index(SheetA!$B:$G;MATCH($A2;SheetA!$B:$G;0)))
```

Which doesn't seem to work either. But I know I probably made an error with this formula.

The function only gives me the value in cell B, it doesn't calculate the average for the 6 cells on the same row. Text1 and Text5 are the texts to Match from SheetB in SheetB

##SheetA##

```
A       B   C   D   E   F   G

Text1   1   2   3   1   2   3
Text2   2   3   1   1   1   1
Text3   1   1   2   1   2   2
Text4   3   5   2   4   5   1
Text5   4   2   2   2   2   2
```

##SheetB##
What I would like on SheetB:

```
A       B
Text1   2
Text5   2.33
```

The formula I showed Previously gets me the following, it doesn't calculate the average, only gets me the first value:

```
A       B
Text1   1
Text5   4
```

It matches the right row with Text1 from SheetA and SheetB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this will work if you have the data as I show. If not, you need to adapt the MATCH part to make sure the formula will work.

Data in SheetA is like this, **starting at row 1** (this is important):

[image]

My formula is in SheetB in column B, and is like this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("SheetA!B"&MATCH(A1;SheetA!A:A;0)&":G"&MATCH(A1;SheetA!A:A;0)))
```

And I get this:

[image]

**How this works:**

1. MATCH will get the row number of the range you want to average (if found, ofc). Because my data starts at row 1, the number returned by MATCH is good. If your data does not start at row 1, you need to adjust it (+1,+2, whatever you need).
2. INDIRECT will return the range in same row, but between columns B and G from SheetA
3. Finally, AVERAGE will make the average.

There is no error handling if something is not found, but if you need it, just add something like IFERROR.

Also, MATCH will only work if the match is 100% exact. In your example in SheetA you have `Text1` but in SheetB you typed `Text 1`, which are not equal. Make sure you type them right.

Hope you can adap this to your needs.

Comment: It is exactly what I needed to do ! Thanks a lot ! 
Upvoted and marked as answer.